# JS wrap every text row into span

Tags: javascript

How can i wrap every text row into span?

From this code:

```
<p>
jkhkjh kjhjh jkhj
hghghjg hjg hj gh
hghkj jk kk
</p>
```

Desired result:

```
<p>
<span>jkhkjh kjhjh jkhj</span>
<span>hghghjg hjg hj gh</span>
<span>hghkj jk kk</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

vanilla JS

```
 var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    p.innerHTML = '<span>' + p.innerHTML.split('\n').join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
```